# MS Access SQL: Return data from 1 table based on a summed total in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have 2 MS Access tables:

Table_A (2 fields)

```
MC    Description           
1234   Item_1             
2345   Item_2            
3456   Item_3
```

Table_B (3 fields)

```
MC    Location  Quantity  
1234   AAA        0  
1234   BBB        0  
1234   CCC        1  
2345   AAA        0  
2345   BBB        0  
2345   CCC        0  
3456   AAA        1  
3456   BBB        1  
3456   CCC        1
```

I am trying to return items from Table_A where the SUM of Quantity (for a given MC) in Table_B > 0

From the above data the following would be returned.

MC     Description
1234---Item_1
3456---Item_3

If the query were changed to = 0 then only MC 2345 would be returned.
If the query were changed to = 1 then only MC 1234 would be returned.

My current attempt is as follows for an = 0 query; however, if using the above data it returns MC 1234 and 2345 when the correct return would be only 2345

```
Query1 = "SELECT mat_MaterielCode, mat_DescriptionShort " & _
    "FROM mat_MaterielMaster " & _
    "INNER JOIN mml_MaterielMasterLocation " & _
    "ON mat_MaterielMaster.mat_MaterielCode = mml_MaterielMasterLocation.mml_MaterielCode " & _
    "WHERE (([mat_MaterielMaster]![mat_SpareClass] IN ('OBS')) AND ([mml_MaterielMasterLocation]![mml_SOH]=0)) " & _
    "GROUP BY mat_MaterielMaster.mat_MaterielCode, mat_MaterielMaster.mat_DescriptionShort "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may looking for this Select Command

```
SELECT MC,Description
FROM Table_A 
WHERE MC IN (SELECT MC FROM Table_B GROUP BY MC HAVING SUM(Quantity) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the query designer?

First create your base query on Table_B, group by MC and Sum(Quantity) > 0.

Then join the result with Table_A on MC.

When you have this working, you can take the SQL from the queries, and build a dynamic SQL in VBA from it (with the first query being a part of the join).

But you seem to be trying to do it the other way around, this is not the best idea.